# How to down weight the average in SQLITE3 and Python

Tags: python, math, sqlite

So I'm knee deep in my first Python project.

I wondered if someone can help me downweight the returned average from an SQLITE3 query?

I'm currently using DESC LIMIT to get 3 averages of a data set then averaging the three results. But this is very tedious and inaccurate.

Is there a simple function to reduce the importance of older data by rowid? I've searched everywhere but I'm struggling to find a simplified answer.

My current query in Python:

```
c.execute("SELECT "
                "AVG(HomeGoals),AVG(AwayGoals)"
                "FROM (SELECT HomeGoals,AwayGoals FROM '%s' WHERE AwayId='%s' AND Year<='%s' AND rowid<'%s' AND Year>'%s' ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT '%s')" %
                (League,each['AwayID'],current_season_year,each['rowid'],previous_year,desc_limit))
```

Example Data:

```
rowid   HomeGoals
1       3
2       1
3       5
4       6
5       2
```

So for example AVG(HomeGoals) with the above data would return the average from the HomeGoals column which is 3.4

What I want to do is add less weighting to older results so for example HomeGoals on rowid 5 would have less significance than HomeGoals on rowid 1. The hope is to return an adjusted average by giving older results less significance.

I hope this makes sense, I've looked at exponential down weighting but I have no idea how to implement it.
Thank You

Comment: Please provide example data, the desired result, and how it is to be computed.

Comment: Hi CL I've edited my question I hope it makes a bit more sense?

Comment: There are many ways of weighing the values. Which one do you want?

Comment: I've been doing some more googling and it seems EWMA from the pandas library does the trick but I would appreciate some advice on how to implement it with the data set example? link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html